# How do I get rid of the parse error when trying to open my PHP file on the browser

Tags: php, filezilla

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/stud/0/1914529/public_html/index.php on line 7 - This is the error, I am confused cause there is nothing on line 7

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A22Dc.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please don't post links to photographs of code. In any case, neither Filezilla nor your browser know or care about PHP syntax.

Comment: As there is no `:` in line 7 you are most likely checking the wrong file or have not uploaded the new version.